# Sorting many rows individually, and adding labels

Tags: excel, data-visualization, google-sheets-api

I have a pivot table with many survey response summaries as formatted below.

```
+-----------+---------+--------+---------+----------+------------+-------+
| Response  | Alabama | Alaska | Arizona | Arkansas | California | Etc.. |
+-----------+---------+--------+---------+----------+------------+-------+
| Cool      | 7       | 8      | 10      | 8        | 87         | ..    |
| Boring    | 12      | 9      | 11      | 1        | 12         | ..    |
| Hot       | 1       | 61     | 17      | 9        | 53         | ..    |
| Cold      | 14      | 37     | 98      | 84       | 85         | ..    |
| Expensive | 56      | 8      | 9       | 6        | 2          | ..    |
| etc..     | ..      | ..     | ..      | ..       | ..         | ..    |
+-----------+---------+--------+---------+----------+------------+-------+
```

It extends downwards to over 1,000 rows, and across 50 columns (states).

**What's the quickest way of ending up with ranking of the words for each state like below?**

**NOTE:** *This is not the correct ranking based on the data snippet above. It's dummy data used for illustration.*

```
+---------+-----------+---------+---------+-----------+------------+-------+
| Ranking |  Alabama  | Alaska  | Arizona | Arkansas  | California | Etc.. |
+---------+-----------+---------+---------+-----------+------------+-------+
| 1       | Hot       | Cold    | Hot     | Trendy    | Sunny      | ..    |
| 2       | Expensive | Empty   | Dry     | Backwards | Fun        | ..    |
| 3       | Big       | Wet     | Deadly  | Good      | Great      | ..    |
| 4       | Dry       | Icy     | Cool    | Bad       | Best       | ..    |
| 5       | Fun       | Not Bad | Fuego   | Ugly      | Poor       | ..    |
| etc..   | ..        | ..      | ..      | ..        | ..         | ..    |
+---------+-----------+---------+---------+-----------+------------+-------+
```

It seems like this might be straightforward to do, without doing the same operating 50 times manually. Happy to use SQL in Google Sheets to do so!

Comment: Exactly what do you want to rank here? Your example data is not correct? Hot for Alaska has the value 61 but still you want cold to be ranked as number 1 for Alaska??

Comment: Both of the snippets are example ata - my real data is much messier. As such, the bottom snippet isn't the _true_ outcome of the first snippet. 

I'm looking to create a ranking of words based on frequency.

Comment: If you want a relevant answer, please provide relevant information, examples and data.